# Limit Python log file

Tags: logging, python-3.x

I'm using Python3 (Ubuntu 14.04) to write out a log file.  I want to limit the size of the log file and so chose `RotatingFileHandler`.  Additionally, I don't want to rotate the log files (.log becomes .log.1 and so on) - I just want to limit the size of the log file.

I've tried using `RotatingFileHandler` like this:

```
filehandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler( "app.log", "a", 1000, 0, None, True )
logging.basicConfig( format = "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level = logging.DEBUG, handlers = [ filehandler ] )
```

What I'm finding is the log file continues to grow and is never truncated or "wrapped" at the limit.

I would have thought setting `backupCount = 0` would cause the log file size to be checked before writing and if there's room for the log message, write it, otherwise empty the file and write out the message.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Bernmeister.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look at the [source code of the RotatingFileHandler](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/logging/handlers.py?revision=79373&view=markup), you will see that a `backupCount` of 0 just closes and then reopens the log's stream.  Here is a modified version that does what you want, discarding the old file:

```
import os
import logging
import logging.handlers


class TruncatedFileHandler(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', maxBytes=0, encoding=None, delay=0):
        super(TruncatedFileHandler, self).__init__(
            filename, mode, maxBytes, 0, encoding, delay)

    def doRollover(self):
        """Truncate the file"""
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
        dfn = self.baseFilename + ".1"
        if os.path.exists(dfn):
            os.remove(dfn)
        os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
        os.remove(dfn)
        self.mode = 'w'
        self.stream = self._open()
```

Here is how to use it:

```
filehandler = TruncatedFileHandler("app.log", "w", 1000)
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    level=logging.DEBUG, handlers=[filehandler])

logger = logging.getLogger('spam_application')

for i in range(100):
    logger.debug("a log line, number: %s", i)
```

And proof that it works

```
❯❯❯ python3.4 main.py
❯❯❯ cat app.log*
2014-06-11 11:50:44,871 - spam_application - DEBUG - a log line, number: 91
2014-06-11 11:50:44,872 - spam_application - DEBUG - a log line, number: 92
2014-06-11 11:50:44,872 - spam_application - DEBUG - a log line, number: 93
2014-06-11 11:50:44,872 - spam_application - DEBUG - a log line, number: 94
2014-06-11 11:50:44,872 - spam_application - DEBUG - a log line, number: 95
2014-06-11 11:50:44,872 - spam_application - DEBUG - a log line, number: 96
2014-06-11 11:50:44,872 - spam_application - DEBUG - a log line, number: 97
2014-06-11 11:50:44,872 - spam_application - DEBUG - a log line, number: 98
2014-06-11 11:50:44,872 - spam_application - DEBUG - a log line, number: 99
```

Comment: @Bernmeister: notice that this solution *completely removes old logs at the moment of rollover*.  Probably it is easy to only discard an amount of them and continue appending, but I did not have the time to look into this ...

Comment: In `doRollover()`, Why do you remove the file `self.baseFilename + ".1"`...I can't see how any file other than `self.baseFilename` would exist?

Comment: @Bernmeister: I left those statements because, if a Logger is stopped between the `os.rename` and the `os.remove` statement (e.g. because the interpreter crashes), then a leftover file could exist.  But I think you are right in your answer: just removing the `baseFilename` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by logc's answer, I took a more brutal approach: I just delete the log file.

```
class TruncatedFileHandler( logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler ):
    def __init__( self, filename, mode = "a", maxBytes = 0, encoding = None, delay = 0 ):
        super( TruncatedFileHandler, self ).__init__( filename, mode, maxBytes, 0, encoding, delay )


    def doRollover( self ):
        if self.stream: self.stream.close()

        if os.path.exists( self.baseFilename ): os.remove( self.baseFilename )

        self.mode = "a" # Not sure why but "w" behaves in the same way as "a".
        self.stream = self._open()
```

One point I've found with my solution and that of logc's is once `doRollover()` is called, setting `self.mode="a"` or `self.mode="w"` makes no difference in terms of writing to the file.  That is, I expected "w" to start writing from the beginning of the file EACH time but it does not (it behaves in the same way as "a" and writes from the last place it wrote).

Comment: Just a small comment: `"a"` behaves the same as `"w"` because, if the file does not exist -- and you have just deleted it --, appending to the file is the same as writing to the file.  In the original code, I think they change to "w" (from "a") to ensure that the file is *created* from scratch after rolling over all the other files to other names.