# Limit a single log file to a specific size

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Using python logging module ([RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#rotatingfilehandler)), I want to limit logging to a single file to a certain size. I haven't find anything that allows limiting the log file size in just a single file.

This is my config:

```
[handler_fileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('logs/export.log','a',800,1)
```

The last two arguments in `args` are `maxBytes` and `backupCount`. Setting `backupCount` to `0` would stop file rotation. Setting it to `1` would create another file.

I cant use `FileHandler` class since it doesn't has a file size config thats why I am using RotatingFileHandler class instead. Am I missing something or is there a way this can be done?

**Update:**

Found a workaround from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157278/limit-python-log-file)
. But the solution implements a `TruncatedFileHandler` class using `RotatingFileHandler`. Its an old post (2014). So the official logging module hasn't implemented something similar to this?

Comment: what is `maxBytes` doing?

Comment: Its the file size