# Python How to remove logs history from generated log file after reaching to certain bytes

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am using yaml configuration file to create log handlers using logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler, in the configuration file i have given maxBytes 10Mb,

Please find the below for reference

```
  logging:
  version: 1
  formatters:
    simple:
      format: "%(asctime)s - %(lineno)d - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s"
  handlers:
    console:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      level: DEBUG
      formatter: simple
      stream: ext://sys.stdout

    info_file_handler:
      class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
      level: DEBUG
      formatter: simple
      filename: info.log
      maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
      backupCount: 20
      encoding: utf8

    error_file_handler:
      class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
      level: ERROR
      formatter: simple
      filename: errors.log
      maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
      backupCount: 20
      encoding: utf8

  root:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console, info_file_handler, error_file_handler]
```

Now once log file is generated ex:**info.log** and reaches to 10MB it creates another file example **info1.log** to append new logs.
but i would like delete the old logs history once it reaches to 10MB, and write the logs again to the same file.
I don not wanted to create new file to append new logs.

Comment: RotatingFileHandler will move the old logs to info.log.1, info.log.2, etc, and continue to write new logs to info.log. You could set `backupCount` to 1 and `maxBytes` to 5MB if you want to keep up to 10MB of logs (info.log + info.log.1). Setting `backupCount` to 0 will disable rollover. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler

Comment: One approach is to subclass `RotatingFileHandler` and write your own `doRollover()` that will overwrite the existing file instead of writing to a new file. Someone has already implemented this, see [Limit Python log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157278/limit-python-log-file).

Comment: @kielni, (info.log + info.log.1) ?? i did not understand !!  as you said if i keep ``backuoCount`` to 1 and ``maxBytes`` to 5MB it doest create new file when it reaches to 5MB instead it will delete older log history and append new logs to existing file (info.log) ??

Comment: @ Nikolaos Chatzis , from the example you mentioned, they are doing it programmatically, but my log file configurations are in yaml file, i am looking for some configuration i can add in yaml file for `RotatingFileHandler` possible ?

Comment: If you set `backupCount` to 1 and `maxBytes` to 5MB, you will have one active log file (info.log) and one backup log file (info.log.1). New data will always go to info.log. When the info.log file reaches 5MB, it will rollover the data to info.log.1 (the backup).